# Hide/show inner divs on hover in an accordion with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

kindly take a look at my HTML code below:

```
<div class="accordion">
<ul>
   <li class="box1">
     <div class="normal"> CONTENT HERE </div>
     <div class="expanded"> CONTENT HERE </div>
     <div class="hidden"> CONTENT HERE </div>
   </li>
   <li class="box2">
     <div class="normal"> CONTENT HERE </div>
     <div class="expanded"> CONTENT HERE </div>
     <div class="hidden"> CONTENT HERE </div>
   </li>
   <li class="box3">
     <div class="normal"> CONTENT HERE </div>
     <div class="expanded"> CONTENT HERE </div>
     <div class="hidden"> CONTENT HERE </div>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Basically it's an accordion powered by a jQuery plugin. It has 3 boxes and depending on which box the user is hovering on, I wish to have the inner divs (normal, expanded, hidden) shown or hidden. Here are the scenarios:

1. On default, all div.normal will be shown by default, div.expanded and div.hidden will be hidden.
2. When user hovers on li.box1 for example, its div.expanded will be shown and div.normal and div.hidden will be hidden. For li.box2 and li.box3 then however, only div.hidden will be shown respectively, the rest of the divs will be hidden.

I have begun with the code but I don't think it's going anywhere. (I am a designer, you see.)

It sounds complicated but I know it can be easily done via jQuery, to anyone who can help, I'd really appreciate it.

UPDATE: 
Here's what I've done so far.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".accordion li").hover(function () {

    $(this).siblings().children(".normal").hide();
    $(this).siblings()..children(".hidden").delay(700).show();
    $(this).children(".expanded").delay(700).show();

    }, function () {

    $(this).siblings().children(".normal").delay(700).fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).siblings().children(".hidden").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).children(".expanded").fadeOut("fast");

  });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you include a link to the jQuery library or function you've attempted this with? Also, if you've tried any JavaScript/jQuery on this, that would also be really helpful for you to include.

Comment: I have included my codes. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Also, good job describing the *desired* behavior; next, can you describe what the *actual* behavior is that you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.expanded').hide();

        $('.box1').hover(function(){
                    $('.expanded').show();
        });
});
```

This is how you can hide and show DOM elements in jQuery. Please get that set according to the way you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can initially hide divs by using style='display:none'
for hover event;

```
  $("li.box1").hover(function(){
     $(this).find('.expanded').show();
     $(this).find('.hidden').show();
    $(this).find('.normal').hide();
 });
```